# How do I make Gson use Externalizables?

Tags: java, gson

I have the following `User.class` (just an example):

```
public class User implements Externalizable {

    int id;
    String username;
    public User(String username, int id) {
        this.username = username;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {}

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(id +"_" + username);
    }

}
```

This is how I save the users:

```
 Gson testson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
 Map<String, User> userStorage = new HashMap<>();
 userStorage.put("test_user_1", new User("TestUser1", 213));
 userStorage.put("test_user_2", new User("TestUser2", 999));
 userStorage.put("test_user_3", new User("TestUser3", 3));
 writer.write(testson.toJson(userStorage));
 writer.close();
```

The output file looks like this:

```
{
  "test_user_3": {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "TestUser3"
  },
  "test_user_1": {
    "id": 213,
    "username": "TestUser1"
  },
  "test_user_2": {
    "id": 999,
    "username": "TestUser2"
  }
}
```

Insead of what I expected:

```
{
  "test_user_3": "3_TestUser3",
  "test_user_1": "213_TestUser1",
  "test_user_2": "999_TestUser2"
}
```

If I make `Gson` ignore the `id` and `username` (`transient` or via the `@Expose` feature) the result just looks like that:

```
{
  "test_user_3": {},
  "test_user_1": {},
  "test_user_2": {}
}
```

So my question is: How do I make `Gson` use the `Externalizable` methods that i've overridden? Is `GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter()` used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But you can write a [custom User serializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer):

```
public class UserSerializer implements JsonSerializer<User> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(User src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.id + "_" + src.username);
    }
}
```

And configure the Gson instance to use the serializer for the User type:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserSerializer())
        .create();
```

Comment: For me, JsonSerializer#serialize is a void. Edit: Fail. I accidentelly imported Jackson

Comment: Here is a working gist with imports: https://gist.github.com/squallified/6111cb5dd60c742f28f0